# How can I see former major share holders of a company?

Tags: stocks, shares, research

I'm attempting to research share holders of companies in the present and in the past.

I've been able to find specific names on Yahoo that are current, for example:
[http://finance.yahoo.com/q/mh?s=WFC+Major+Holders](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/mh?s=WFC%20Major%20Holders)

Does anyone know how I can look up major share holders for people earlier this year? I can't seem to find anything online but I'm sure there is somewhere I can see it easily, like mentioned above, for past share holders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option in some cases is the Wayback Machine (web.archive.org) to literally see what that page said at a particular date/time:

http://web.archive.org/web/20110904025058/http://finance.yahoo.com/q/mh?s=MSFT+Major+Holders

For example.  Some pages are there, some aren't; I couldn't find your Wells Fargo page, for example.

Comment: This worked for what I was trying to do actually and was very simple. Thank you! ☺

Answer (score 4):

You have to go backwards through form 3's and form 4's (change in ownership for holders greater than 5%) and form 13F's (hedge fund holding reports) and more research into the original source of funding of a company

Comment: Probably just being dumb trying to find the navigation options on there but I can't find where to go through the forms.

Comment: @Eric they are typically listed on Edgar-online, of which Yahoo has a link. http://yahoo.brand.edgar-online.com/default.aspx?cik=72971